# How can I install 32 bit JDK on Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: java, ubuntu

How can I install 32 bit JDK on Ubuntu 64bit? I need to install it as I am having some problem with eclipse for android development.

Comment: Is there a specific JDK you want?  OpenJDK?  Oracle JDK?  Also, what version of java are you wanting?

Comment: If possible I would suggest using Android Studio. It provides a better experience then eclipse IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The OpenJDK is part of Ubuntu's `main` repository, so it can be installed with the usual Ubuntu tools. You want package `openjdk-7-jdk` or `openjdk-8-jdk`.

Thanks to the "[MultiArch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch)" feature Ubuntu inherited from Debian, you can install the 32-bit version of a package on a 64-bit system using the usual tools, such as `apt-get` or `aptitude`. Just append `:i386` to the package name. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386
```

Any required i368 libraries will then be installed automatically.